# How to connect to azure SQL from TeamCity on azure VM for publishing

Tags: azure, teamcity, azure-sql-database, publish, azure-virtual-machine

I'm learning how to configure TeamCity right now.
My TeamCity runs on Azure VM. My SQL DB is on Azure SQL.
I have solution with web project and SQL project. I've created publish config in SQL project for publishing to Azure SQL. From Visual Studio on my PC I can publish DB project with this publish config to Azure SQL.
From Teamcity on Azure VM I can publish Web project from solution to my Azure Web App. But when I try to publish the SQL project to Azure SQL from TeamCity I get following error:

```
*** Could not deploy package.
Unable to connect to target server.
Process exited with code 1
Step Command Line failed
```

The current IP of my Azure VM is set in Azure SQL firewall config.

The command line build step is such:

```
"<Path to sqlpackage.exe>\sqlpackage.exe" 
/Action:Publish 
/SourceFile:<path to generated dacpac in previous build step>\<db proj name>.dacpac 
/Profile:<path to publish config>\azureSql.publish.xml
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is the content of publish config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeCompositeObjects>True</IncludeCompositeObjects>
    <TargetDatabaseName>MyDbName</TargetDatabaseName>
    <DeployScriptFileName>MyDbName.Database.sql</DeployScriptFileName>
    <TargetConnectionString>Data Source=tcp:<myuser>.database.windows.net,1433;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=<user name>;Pooling=False</TargetConnectionString>
    <ScriptDatabaseOptions>True</ScriptDatabaseOptions>
    <BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>False</BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>
    <ProfileVersionNumber>1</ProfileVersionNumber>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have this error because of tons of reasons. Can you check this for me:

1. You are able to connect to SQL Azure DB from Azure VM (using command line tool, management studio, etc).
2. You configured your deploy script correctly. Try to run the same command from local machine.
3. Generally, if you need to connect to SQL Azure from Azure DC, you need just to allow "azure services" to access your database. Check this one also.

Answer (score 2):

My guesses ordered by relevancy:

1. Firewall (both TC and Azure Sql server)
2. Connection info:

   - **myuser**.database.windows.net should be dbname instead
   - You need to tell sqlproj to [keep password as part of config](http://screencast.com/t/dI7XDVzMiQzr)

     - it`s better to keep the password outside of source code. Read it as part of integration server build process from secure storage and refer to [sqlpackage docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx) to learn how to specify the target connection string.
3. If items above do not help use **/Quiet:False** option to get more details on failure.